# Joint density of two functions of a uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, covariance, density-function, uniform-distribution

I'd like to work out $\operatorname{Cov}(\cos(2U), \cos(3U))$ where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, \pi]$.

I believe this involves computing $\mathbb{E}[\cos(2U)\cos(3U)]$. If so, then I first need the joint density, which I'm stuck on.

I can work out the density of $\cos(3U)$; this is similar to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/309400). $f_{\cos(3U)}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$, $x \in (-1, 1)$. But that and $f_{\cos(2U)}(x)$ are only (directly) useful for individual expected values.

How do I work out the joint density?

(In [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/224105/364080), the joint density seems to be $1$. Don't know why though.)

Comment: You don't need the joint density to find this expectation, thanks to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician.

Comment: Much easier now.

Comment: If you consider that for a given value of $X=\cos(2U)$, then either (i) $Y=\cos(3U)$ takes one of two possible values, equal in magnitude and opposite in sign (one from $U<\pi/2$, one from $U>\pi/2$), or (ii) $Y$ is $0$; then it's immediately clear that  the pair of possible values are equally probable and hence that their corresponding contributions to the covariance cancel. Given $X$ and $Y$ are both bounded, immediately $E(XY)=0$.